# New design: 10k+ tools need a rethink

Tags: discussion, design

I can't put my finger on why, but the redesign has made the 10k+ tools really difficult to read now. Either there's not enough space between the entries on the lists, or the new font needs some colour or size adjustment.

Comment: The font size is really inconsistent now…